# Debian Stretch 9.3 can't configure DHCP

Tags: debian, system-installation, dhcp

I am installing Debian stretch 9.3 from a USB stick and I am getting a DHCP configuration error `cannot configure dhcp automatically`

I tried using :  direct cable to the router LAN & a wireless adapter TP-LINK but both results the same error.

alt + f4 tty gives the following error:

```
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on enp0s3...
Timed out.
No response.

Sending discover ........
Sending select for 192.168.1.3 ....
udhcp: has been called with an unknown param lease fail
```

Any suggestion or help would be very appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: if you are not experienced it might be easier starting with the DVD1 image than the netinst image. netinst wont support all the hardware you throw at it.

Comment: I have quite a while with linux actually but this point i didn't pay attention to ! i will try to figure the issue but if i cant i will go with the DVD image.

Comment: @Rui what hardware have you encountered that’s supported by DVD1 but not netinst? I wouldn’t have thought there would be any difference (unlike netinst+firmware), apart from the fact that the network isn’t necessary to install off DVD1...

Comment: @StephenKitt Too long ago to remember I am afraid - I think they were HP or Dell servers. But yeah, namely DVD1 allows you to install stuff without still having a network connection. I have not installed Debian from scratch for quite a while now I am afraid.

Comment: @Lotfio, if you press Alt+F4 after DHCP fails, you'll get more detailed information about what went wrong; could you try again and see if there's anything relevant there?

Comment: @Rui that sounds like tg3 or Broadcom Ethernet requiring firmware, if my experience with HP and Dell hardware from a few years ago is anything to go by :-/.

Comment: @StephenKitt post updated !

Comment: If you don't need the IPv6 turn it off : [DebianIPv6](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6)

Comment: @GAD3R system not yet installed where i am going to find the grub file :p

Comment: Configure the network manually , do not use the auto-detection.

Comment: @GAD3R i aleady did ! it works on that step but later on at apt list configuration it fails because connection cannot be established which means the same error !

Comment: During the the configuration of `apt` (during system install)?

Comment: @GAD3R yep when i choose a miror for apt it tries to connect but it fails !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71136/discussion-between-gad3r-and-lotfio-lakehal).